# Embedding of $S^n$ to the smooth strictly convex region in $R^{n+1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-geometry, support-function

Assuming $D\subset R^{n+1}$ is smooth and strictly convex region, one can construct an embedding $\varphi$ of $S^n$ to the boundary $\partial D$ of $D$ which associates to each direction $z\in S^n$ the point of $\partial D$ with normal $z$, where $S^n$ is unit  sphere. This is given by
$$
\varphi(z)= s(z)z+\nabla s(z)   \tag{1}
$$
where $s$ is support function of $D$,
$$
s(z)=\sup_{y\in D} \langle y, z\rangle
$$

and $\nabla s$ is the gradient vector of $s$ with respect to the standard metric $g$ on $S^n$.

The above statement is from   *Andrews, Ben*, [**Entropy estimates for evolving hypersurfaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/CAG.1994.v2.n1.a3), Commun. Anal. Geom. 2, No. 1, 53-64 (1994). [ZBL0839.53049](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0839.53049).

I want to show the $\varphi(z)$ is the point of $\partial D$ with normal $z$, but don't know how to begin.   There are two things need to be proved:

1, How to show $\varphi(z)\in \partial D$ ?

2, How to show the normal of $\varphi(z)$ is $z$?

Besides, assuming $\{e_1, ...,e_n\}$ is a local basis of $S^n$, I understand the gradient vector $\nabla s$ is
$$
\nabla s = g^{ij}(\nabla _{e_i} s)  e_j
$$